# Why doesn't Default route work using Html.ActionLink in this case?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, http-status-code-404, actionlink

I have a rather peculiar issue with routing.

Coming back to routing after not having to worry about configuration for it for a year, I am using the default route and ignore route for resources:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",

        // URL with parameters
        new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        });
```

I have a `RulesController` with an action for `Index` and `Lorem` and a `Index.aspx`, `Lorem.aspx` in Views > Rules directory.

I have an ActionLink aimed at Rules/Index on the maseter page:

```
<li><div><%: Html.ActionLink("linkText", "Index", "Rules")%></div></li>
```

The link is being rendered as `http://localhost:12345/Rules/` and am getting a 404.

When I type `Index` into the URL the application routes it to the action.

When I change the default route action from `"Index"` to `"Lorem"`, the action link is being rendered as `http://localhost:12345/Rules/Index` adding the `Index` as it's no longer on the default route and the application routes to the Index action correctly.

I have used [Phil Haack's Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx), but entering the url `http://localhost:12345/Rules/` is causing a 404 using that too.

I think I've covered all of the rookie mistakes, relevant SO questions and basic RTFMs.

I'm assuming that "Rules" isn't any sort of reserved word in routing.
Other than updating the Routes and debuugging them, what can I look at?

Comment: Do you have any IgnoreRoutes defined? Do you by chance have a folder called 'Rules' in your website directory?

Comment: I do have the default ignore route (added in the question now) and yes on the folder; the architect hasn't created another project for Business Objects, so there's a "Rules" folder there. I'll reorganise and test. Add this comment as an answer in case that's it.

Comment: Been there, done that. Took me quite a while to find the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there is not a folder called 'Rules' in the same directory as your website. In its default configuration, ASP.NET MVC routes will respect physical paths before route definitions. If there is a route defined which matches the path to a physical folder in the website, the routing engine will be bypassed completely.

You can disable routing to physical paths by changing the `RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles` property to `false`, but if you do this and your application has paths to physical resources (such as images, scripts, stylesheets, etc) you will need to accommodate for those paths with matching IgnoreRoute() definitions. 
For example: `RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("content/{*pathInfo}");`.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, the second paragraph is particularly interesting and useful.